# What is the significance of the "I've got a black lake in my eye!" line in The Stranger?

Tags: dialogue, the-stranger-2022

In the crime-thriller movie, *[The Stranger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11897478/reference/)* (2022), in a dream scene, the undercover police officer drives his car with Henry (the suspected child kidnapper/murderer). All of a sudden and seemingly unrelated to their current conversation, Henry shouts: "*I've got a black lake in my eye!*" in a distorted and devilish voice (serving as a jump scare).

What is the significance of this line of dialogue? I thought it would be a religious reference, but have not found anything.

Comment: @JonathanDearborn Answers should be posted as answers, not as edits to the question itself. I have no idea how your edit got approved, but I'm rolling it back.

Comment: @F1Krazy:  It was apparently approved by the OP.  But it still wasn't a good use of the edit feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earlier in the movie, there is a mention of anxiety and negative emotions accumulating till they become a 'lake' within you. Apart from the distressful imagery the phrase summons, it also signifies the deep evil and darkness that Mark discovers in Henry, as well as the infinite, terminal stress that Henry lives with after commiting multiple assaults and murders.
Later in the movie they also stop by the dark lake where Henry dumped the boy's clothes in, so the line is also a foreshadowing of that.